# Understanding evaluation summary in stanford sentiment tool

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can anyone help me out to understand the evaluation summary while testing against a trained model? What is label confusion matrix and root label confusion matrix?

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix . We track (mis-)classifications for each label / root label and use this table structure to report the results.